# Create Multiple User Controls at Runtime

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, runtime

I'm trying to create multiple user controls at runtime and keep track of them using either some kind of index or naming method.

My code thus far creates the user control, but as soon as I click to create the next one, the previous one disappears and then it creates the new one.

Here is my code so far - what am I missing?

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim plBox As New PlayerBox
    Dim plBoxInt As Int32 = 0

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim plBoxHeight As Int32 = plBox.Height

        If plBox.Created = True Then
            plBoxInt += 1
        End If
        plBox.Name = "plBox" & plBoxInt.ToString()
        plBox.Top = plBoxHeight * plBoxInt

        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(plBox)
    End Sub
End Class
```

So far I tried searching through a couple of sites but can't really find the reason why it shouldn't work. Any help would be great.

Comment: You are not creating n controls, but redefining n times the properties of just one control. To avoid this problem, make plBox local to Button3_click (i.e., write Dim plBox As New PlayerBox inside this method).

Answer (score 0):

To update...
I managed to add the User Created Controls and are now able to remove them.
Here is my next problem. I need to click a button on the User Control and run/call a subroutine on the form it was created on.

Here's the code:

Public Class frmMain

```
Public plBoxList As New List(Of PlayerBox)

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim plBox As New PlayerBox

    Dim plBoxHeight As Int32 = plBox.Height

    plBox.Name = "plBox" & plBoxList.Count.ToString()
    plBox.Top = plBoxHeight * plBoxList.Count

    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(plBox)
    plBoxList.Add(plBox)

    AddHandler plBox.btnRemove.Click, AddressOf plBox.btnRemove.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Refresh_plBox_List()

    Dim plBoxIndex As Int32 = 0
    Dim plBoxRem As Boolean = False

    For Each plBox In plBoxList

        If plBox.Name = "DISPOSE" Then
            plBoxIndex = plBoxList.IndexOf(plBox)
            plBoxRem = True
        End If

    Next

    If plBoxRem = True Then
        plBoxList.RemoveAt(plBoxIndex)
    End If

    For Each plBox In plBoxList

        plBox.Top = plBox.Height * plBoxList.IndexOf(plBox)

    Next

End Sub
End Class
```